# How Best to Use UWP FullTrustProcessLauncher to Launch Seperate Unity Game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, windows-10, desktop-bridge

I am working for a client who wants a UWP Portal App and a Pac-Man clone game that can be launched from inside the Portal App.  I set up the FullTrustProcessLauncher capability in the UWP App to handle launch the exe for the game.  I also had to add a post-build item to copy the exe and accompanying data folder to the AppX folder of the build.  The FullTrustProcessLauncher fires the exe fine, but I keep getting the "Data folder not found error".

So my questions are this:
1. Why does it keep saying the folder is missing, but it would be right next to it?
2. Is there a better way to do this?

In full disclosure, this is my first app I've created and my first post on StackOverflow.

- I have the Build options of the Unity project set to .NET 2.0, but that doesn't fix the issue
- I have added the Pac-Man folder to my Visual Studio, but had to do the XCOPY so it was accessible

I want the Pac-Man app to launch like it would from navigating to the folder and launching the exe

Comment: Are you using the "Windows Packaging Project" in Visual Studio to package up both your projects? If not, that would be the first step to do to address some of the challenges you are referencing in your post.

Comment: Hey Stefan, thanks for responding to my post!  From what I see about the Windows Packaging Project, my Pac-Man app would need to be a VS solution to be added to the project, which it currently is not.  Or can I add non-VS solutions to the package?

Comment: If this is a pre-built EXE you could just add this (and any required supporting files) as "Content" to your UWP project. Make sure you set them up as "Copy to output". Alternatively you could add a dummy project for your PacMan files that just copies those files to its build output - this way you could leverage the packaging project.

Comment: I'll try option A before going for the dummy project.  In option A, I wouldn't have to do my XCOPY in my build output, right?  It should just move the folders for me that way, then I can just access the file as normal

Comment: Correct. Just make sure the "Copy to Output Directory" property is set correctly in VS for all files that are required in the package.

Comment: Posted option A as answer now. Please mark as answered if it solved your problem. If not let me know what is the remaining problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include your EXE (and any required supporting files) as "Content" to your UWP project. Make sure you set them up as "Copy to output". Then you declare the FullTrustProcess extension in the appxmanifest to point at your included EXE, and use the FullTrustProcessLauncher API to launch it from the UWP.

Some more info here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher 
https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/

Comment: Sorry, I was waiting on the client to respond back to me on whether it worked or not.  It was always working on my machine, lol.  Everything worked, thanks so much!  Wish I had asked months ago :)

Comment: what is not entirely clear is how to use a separate .exe file that is not a visual studio project. Your explanation seems straight forward, but I am not sure if I need use a Package project or not (because you reference to a blog tutorial on this using a Package project). Would be nice to elaborate on that.