# UWP FullTrustProcess - actually controlling the process

Tags: c#, uwp, process, windows-10, desktop-bridge

In WPF, I have used this code to control the process of an external .exe file:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    Verb = "runas",
    FileName = executePath,//Client.exe path within the WPF application
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
};

Process scanProcess = new Process
{
    StartInfo = info,
    EnableRaisingEvents = true
};

int procId = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id;
Process[] existingProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("Client.exe");
foreach (Process process in existingProcess)
{
    if (process.Id == procId)
    {
        continue;
    }

    return;//don't run, might have tried to start double
}

scanProcess.Start();
scanProcess.Exited += (s, e) => GoBack();

windowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
IntPtr buttonHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
while (buttonHandle == IntPtr.Zero)//wait till process is fully started, we wait for a button the be available because then we know it is ready
{
    windowHandle = HardwareApi.GetForegroundWindow();
    buttonHandle = HardwareApi.FindWindowEx(windowHandle, IntPtr.Zero, "TPanel", "Start");

}

Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0);
HardwareApi.GetWindowRect(windowHandle, ref rect);
//move window to correct position
var tempX = 500;
var tempY = 600;
HardwareApi.SetWindowPos(windowHandle, new IntPtr(-1), 0, 0, 0, 0, 3u);
HardwareApi.MoveWindow(windowHandle, (int)tempX, (int)tempY, rect.Width, rect.Height - 55, true);
```

As you see, quite a bit of intense process controlling. `HardwareApi` is just a collection of `user32.dll` methods using `DllImport`.

Now I don't mind if not all of these functionalities are possible, but at least I need to be able to start the process and stop it/kill it from out the new UWP application.

So I went through the process of creating an UWP application and a Package application, I followed [this blog](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/), provided by [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55978324/2901207). What is importantly different is that I do not have a separate Visual Studio Project of the external Client.exe, so I did what the mentioned answer said: Copy the Client.exe file (and the dependent files) into the Package project.

Solution view:

[image]

Package.appxmanifest of the Package project includes this part:

```
  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App"
     ....
      <Extensions>
        <desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="Rss\Hardware\Software\RedFolder\Client.exe"/>
      </Extensions>
    </Application>
  </Applications>

  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
   <rescap:Capability Name="allowElevation" />
  </Capabilities>
```

And within the UWP application, I somewhere start the `FullTrustProcess`

Don't forget to go to `Add Reference`-> Universal Windows -> Extensions -> `Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP (latest version)` and add the reference

```
if (ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustAppContract", 1, 0))
{
    await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
}
```

So this all works fine, so now the question is how I can do the following things:

1. Check if the process is running
2. Close the process at a certain time from within the UWP application
3. Move the window to a certain on-screen position (or use other `user32.dll`-like functions.

As per my understanding, App Service within UWP doesn't seem to be a solution, I can't modify the external .exe in such a way that it would receive/connect. If an App Service can be used from only the UWP-side to control a process then that would be great.

Comment: None of those are opinions or decisions on my part. UWP is just WPF, with some features for automatic scaling of the UI and support for App-type rights restrictions. | Since they discontinued Windows 10 Mobile, the only reason to ever use it was that you wanted to programm WPF style against .NET core. With Core 3.0 it will no longer be nessesary.

Comment: W10 mobile is not the only reason to use UWP, UWP enables you to use the Microsoft distribution channels (Windows Store), associate drivers to be automatically installed (Hardware Supported Apps), fluent design is a plus, open app via URL from web (creating a good payment flow, or use built-in microsoft tools), performance, company signing validation thus fully trusted when working with hardware, etc.. But again, this is out of the scope of this question. Yes I agree WPF seems to get some more love atm with Core 3.0, that is a bit unfortunate.

Comment: @CularBytes: A pure UWP app runs in a sandbox and cannot kill processes. What you probably want to is to package your current WPF application as a UWP using a Windows Application Packaging project. Or what exactly are you trying to do? What's the point of converting from WPF to UWP here?

Comment: @mm8 Well if you REALLY want the context: We build an UWP app for above mentioned benefits regarding hardware, long-term an integration will be build using .dll's to communicate with the hardware, unfortunately a temporary workaround has to be created to use the existing manufacturer software, which needs to be limited to a usage of a certain time. I find it weird that a pure UWP runs in a sandbox, but when using a bridge I would be able to use those Process functions.

Comment: @CularBytes: *I find it weird that a pure UWP runs in a sandbox, but when using a bridge I would be able to use those Process functions*. Yes. So what exactly is your current issue?

Comment: @mm8 a way to get more control over the process that is launched via `FullTrustProcessLauncher`. Just like the normal `Process`, after launching it, I can do things with it like killing it. As per your comment and further research I begin to notice that that isn't possible

Comment: @CularBytes: No, that's not possible in a pure UWP app. See my answer.

Comment: One thing you can do is code up a simple controller EXE to your package. Launch this from the UWP via FullTrustProcess launcher and communicate via AppServiceConnection. From the controller EXE you can then use all the System.Diagnostis.Process* APIs to start, check and kill your actual app process - and also use all the user32 function for window manipulation etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve your scenario you need to add a full-trust launcher/controller EXE to your package. Launch this from the UWP via FullTrustProcess launcher and communicate with it via AppServiceConnection. From the controller EXE you can then use all the System.Diagnostis.Process* APIs to start, check and kill your actual app process (Client.exe in your example) - and also use all the user32 function for window manipulation etc.

More info and a sample app on handling multiple processes here:
https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-2/

Info and sample on how to do the communication here:
https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/16/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-3/

Comment: Yes! That is exactly what I end up doing. Create a simple .NET Framework console application, do as you described and then turn it into a `Windows Application` within the properties of the project so that no console window is showing up. Only thing I am currently fighting with is this: https://github.com/microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/issues/93 But that is out of scope for this question.

Comment: @CularBytes I'd recommend opening a new Stackoverflow question for this. Logging an issue in the samples repo may not give you any traction for this problem. Last I checked (I am no longer on the Windows team), AppService connections are not supported for elevated processes. My first thought on this though is: do you actually need Bridge.exe to be elevated, or just Client.exe?

Comment: I should create a new question yes, but perhaps you have the solution right here: Yes, just client.exe needs to be elevated, when starting the process from Bridge.exe it gives a error as expected: `The requested operation requires elevation` using `Verb = "runas"` in `ProcessStartInfo`. As far as I know I can't make windows ask for elevation for a sub-process (although UWP seems to be able to do so when using `<rescap:Capability Name="allowElevation" />` and starting Bridge.exe)

Comment: :O `UseShellExecute` to true of course! Thanks for bringing me to that mindset.

Answer (score 1):

A pure UWP app runs in a sandbox and *cannot* kill processes using the `System.Diagnostics.Process` type in .NET.

What you probably want to is to package your current WPF application as a UWP using a Windows Application Packaging project.

You will then be able to run it as a full-trust application but still take advantage of the streamlined deployment and update experience that UWP brings, as well as using modern UWP APIs side-by-side with your current .NET code.

Comment: Going back to WPF was never an option, but I think I got something...

Comment: This isn't exactly true. You don't have to go back to WPF for this scenario. The app can still be a UWP. To solve the problem move the code that creates/monitors/kills the processes into a FullTrustProcess extension. From there you have the same level of control over processes as from WPF or Win32 apps.

Comment: see my proposed answer for more details