# How to Terminate .exe file in uwp app using fulltrustlauncher?

Tags: c#, uwp, runtime.exec, full-trust

Referring to this: [How to launch .exe file in uwp app using fulltrustlauncher?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45911755/how-to-launch-exe-file-in-uwp-app-using-fulltrustlauncher)

How can i terminate the .exe file after starting it???

Comment: Do you mean that you want to kill the client process from uwp app?

Comment: Umm, don't know, i just want to kill the .exe file started using fulltrsutlauncher. Above link tells us how to start (other\any) .exe file within the uwp app, but i want to know to to terminate that .exe file.

Comment: fulltrsutlauncher has not provide method to kill the extension process, if you want to close it please use System.Diagnostis.Process APIs to start, check and kill your actual app process for more please refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58579906/7254781)